# How to go on the next line when you read a text file in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba, file

Text file "Test_Filename":

test1

test2

test3

test4

Code:

```
Open Test_Filename For Input As #3

Do While Not EOF(3)

    Line Input #3, strLine
    If Left(strLine, 5) = "test2" Then
        strData1 = "test2" + vbCrLf
        strLine = ""
        ' GO TO NEXT LINE
    Else
        ' GO TO NEXT LINE
    End If

    If (strData1 = "test2") And (Left(newstrLine, 5) = "test3") Then
        strData2 = strData2 & newstrLine + vbCrLf
        MsgBox (strData2)
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

Close #3
```

When I meet a specific condition I would to go on the next line, but I don't know how ...
If some have any idea, it will be great. 
Thanks

Comment: Every `Line Input` statement consumes a line in the file... it's not clear in your "code" where the `Do` loop begins.

Comment: how did you get the first line?  .... have you tried to do it twice in a row.  if you did not, why did you not try?

Comment: The Do loop begins with the first line from the file

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/315594-how-do-i-read-next-line-after-a-specific-word-is-read-in-text-file/) should help you. In short, if you use `read.Readline()` you can skip to next line just by running `read.Readline()` again.

Just for reference

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   Dim read As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\New Text.txt")
   Dim a As String

   For Each a In read.ReadLine
       If read.ReadLine.Equals("Test condition") Then
           Label1.Text = read.ReadLine()
       End If
   Next

   End Sub
```

Comment: This VB.NET not VBA. Completely different.

Comment: hmm, OP carrying on with issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028831/how-to-use-append-command-on-specific-position-in-a-text-file-using-visual-bas/47029275?noredirect=1#comment81006506_47029275