# Apply VBA function, for changing font color of specified text in Excel, to a list of specified texts

Tags: excel, vba

The code below changes the font color of all occurrences of a specified string of text in Excel.

I would like to apply it to multiple specified strings of text where the color to which the text is changed would be the same for all supplied text strings.

For example rather than finding all occurrences of cat and changing the font color to blue, it could be applied to "cat", "dog", and "raccoon".

```vb
Sub SearchReplace_Color_PartialCell()
    'modified to catch multiple occurences of search term within the single cell

    Const textToChange = "cat"
    Const newColor = vbBlue
    Dim c As Range 'the cell we're looking at
    Dim pos As Integer 'current position#, where we're looking in the cell (0 = Not Found)
    Dim matches As Integer 'count number of replacements

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells 'loop throgh all cells that have data

        pos = 1

        Do While InStr(pos, c.Value, textToChange) > 0   'loop until no match in cell

            matches = matches + 1

            pos = InStr(pos, c.Value, textToChange)

            c.Characters(InStr(pos, c.Value, textToChange), Len(textToChange)).Font.Color = _
                newColor ' change the color of the text in that position
            pos = pos + 1 'check again, starting 1 letter to the right

        Loop

    Next c

    MsgBox "Replaced " & matches & " occurences of """ & textToChange & """"

End Sub
```

Comment: Store the words in an array?

Comment: FYI you may end up coloring substrings (Eg "cat" would highlight first part of "cattle") with this approach.

Comment: Oh, that's not your code XD

Comment: Definely! I an not really familiar with VBA at all, so I am struggling create an array and run it within the module. I have tried Const textToChange = Array("cat", "dog", and "raccon") and specifying the array and then Const textToChange = myarray, but neither functions. Would you be able to show me how to code the array appropriately?

Comment: No. Sorry not trying at all to take credit for the code displayed there. I do not know how to manage anything in VBA. Link to helpful initial post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030033/change-the-color-of-a-text-with-in-all-the-cells-of-an-excel-sheet

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me people run code they have no idea of.

Comment: I can't help but laugh at this commet :) The idea of using a tool to accomplish a task without fully understanding how the tool works baffles you? SImply think of how often people utilize items they do not fully grasp to accomplish a task. Thanks for the insights and the helpful comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need regex to match on whole word only, and you can use an array of search terms.

For example:

```vb
Sub SearchReplace_Color_PartialCell()
    Const newColor = vbBlue
    Dim c As Range, pos, itm
    Dim matches As Long, arrPos, v

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells 'loop throgh all cells that have data
        v = c.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            For Each itm In Array("cat", "dog", "bear", "aardvark") '<<<< search terms
                arrPos = ExactMatches(CStr(v), CStr(itm))
                If Not IsEmpty(arrPos) Then
                    For Each pos In arrPos
                        c.Characters(pos, Len(itm)).Font.Color = newColor
                        matches = matches + 1
                    Next pos
                End If 'got any matches
            Next itm   'next search term
        End If         'cell has a value
    Next c

    MsgBox "Replaced " & matches & " occurences "

End Sub

'Return an array of 1-based start positions for `lookFor` in `lookIn`
'  whole-word match only.   No return value if no matches.
Function ExactMatches(lookIn As String, lookFor As String) 'as array of start positions
    Static re As Object 'persists between calls
    Dim allMatches, m, i As Long
    
    If re Is Nothing Then  'create if not already created
        Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        re.ignorecase = True
        re.Global = True
    End If
    
    re.Pattern = "\b(" & lookFor & ")\b"
    Set allMatches = re.Execute(lookIn)
    If allMatches.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim arr(1 To allMatches.Count)
        i = 0
        For Each m In allMatches
            i = i + 1
            arr(i) = m.firstindex + 1 'report 1-based positions
        Next m
        ExactMatches = arr
    End If
End Function
```